# ElasticSearch quantity correlation with 2 fields Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch, pandas-groupby, correlation

I have data likes:

```
{a:a1, b:b1, c:c1}
{a:a1, b:b1, c:c2}
{a:a1, b:b2, c:c2}
{a:a2, b:b5, c:c8}
{a:a3, b:b4, c:c6}
```

How can I get all result likes (with ~100M data):

{a1:[b1,b1,b2], a2:[b5], a3[b4]}

Note:

- I mean just like groupby in pandas,
- I only care 2 fields ('a' and 'b')
- Value type of fields 'a' and 'b' are both 'String'
- I had used code below but it didn't return all result.

  TermsAggregationBuilder yearAgg = AggregationBuilders.terms("f1").field("a.keyword")  .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("f2").field("b.keyword"))

Many thanks!!

Comment: Well just set .Size to 10000 if this is enought. If you got more than 10k aggregation (= buckets), usecomposite agg to get all of them using pagination (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html).

Comment: Hi LeBigCat, I had heard about Composite Aggregation, but I don't know how to use it in my case. It will be cool If you suggest some more. Thank you!

Comment: Well i dont know how to write it using java client (syntax), but it s must exist. You need also ex 6.0. The idea of composite agg is to send a first request (juste add thecomposite at the top of your parent aggregation), es will return a first response with a after_key, you just have ask back (another querry) using the key and he will return the next pack.